# Can I setup application insights in another region?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have all my app services in Azure East US, and I was wondering if I could put the Application Insights related to these in Azure West.

My question whether this imposes any noticeable performance hit.

I wonder if East US fails, would application insights (in West) be able to log something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @ZakiMa metioned, they can be set up in different locations and no impact if one of them fails.

**For the performance:**

I just got the feedback from MS application insights team, the answer is no performance issue:

> Application insights sends data to their backend asynchronously - so
> the actual network RT time should not matter.
>
> Also, even though the
> app insights is in East US, the 'ingest' endpoints are globally
> distributed, and telemetry is always sent to the nearest available
> 'ingest' point.

Details are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/299). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to point to existing Application Insights resource (which can be in any location).

If East US fails, other data centers should not be impacted. Application Insights should be able to log everything sent to it (assuming the app running in East US is still running).

**Update**: As Ivan mentioned, ingest endpoints are globally distributed. Though SDK will send data to nearest endpoint, 200 response means that that endpoint persisted data in the right data center.

It will take more time than for the same data center but the performance should not be impacted:

1. There are direct and fast connections between data centers. So, for East US <=> West US (same region) the latency should be minimal.
2. SDKs send data in background in batches, so the latency requirements for ingest calls are not strict for optimal performance (we have many high volume apps which upload telemetry data across regions {not even data centers}).

Comment: Is performance good? Since network latency could now be larger? Say east us and west us.

Comment: Covered this question as well.

Comment: Does this mean that app insights can withstand a datacenter failure within an azure region? So zone redundant in a way.

Comment: Application Insights follows patterns to withstand a datacenter failure (global services will automatically reroute traffic to healthy regions; regional services use hot reservation {every region is paired with either some other one}; available zones {think about them as datacenter consisting of completely independent zones} are used wherever possible. On top of it App Insights just released (still in Public Preview) ability to export data to another Log Analytics workspace (in another region). This is the recommended way for critical payloads which have to be available all the time.